# React Native -Undefined param while coming back to previews screen

Tags: react-native, navigation

I have a root screen called `selectlanguage` once user select his language I'm passing that selected language as params to the `Home` screen, and then to "Home" children. but once I hit back button from that child screen to the `Home` that param turns to `undefined` that why when I want to open that child screen again it cause some issues.

```
Root screen selectedLanguage:

<View style={{ marginTop: 40 }}>
        <Button
            handleClick={() =>
            navigation.navigate('Home', { lan: userLanData.value })
            }
            title={'NEXT'}
            {...}
        />
```

Home screen:

```
  const lan = route.params?.lan;

  // and below i'm passing above param as props to Task screen
          <Tasks
            lanParam={lan}
            {...}
          />
```

Task screen:

```
            //Again passing it to another Child screen
            <TouchableOpacity
                  onPress={() =>
                    navigation.navigate('byWords', {
                      id: item.id,
                      currentLevelName,
                      index,
                      lanParam, <-----
                    })
                  }>
                 {...}
            </TouchableOpacity>
```

Task Child screen:

```
  const lanParam = route?.params?.lanParam;

  const colRef = collection(
    db,
    `${lanParam && lanParam}/${currLevelParam}/tasks/${id}/byWords/`
  );
```

And from this point I had an idea to try send this Param back to home screen while coming back like this:

```
   <Header
        {...}
        goBack={() =>
          navigation.navigate('Home', { index, currLevelParam, lanParam })
        }
      />
```

And now Home screen should look like this and I'm receiving that value back again:

Home screen:

```
  const lan = route.params?.lan;
  const lanParam = route.params?.lanParam;


  // and below i'm passing above param as props to Task screen
          <Tasks
            lanParam={lan}
            {...}
          />
```

**But the problem is that, how could I use that value again since we have no access to the root screen again ?**

Answer (score 0):

it was easy to fix!!

I just modified  `lanParams` to `lan` to keep same as Original param and update Home param again while coming back